# Cheating on USAMTS 2018-2019

Tags: discussion, contests

As some may know, USAMTS round 1 problems have just been released.
To read more about the USAMTS go here: http://www.usamts.org

(From the above link) "Students may use any materials - books, calculators, computers - but all the work must be their own. The USAMTS is run on the honor system - it is an individual competition, whose competitive role is very secondary. **You certainly are allowed to look things up on the Internet. What you may not do is ask another person for help on a problem. Asking the question on a message board or a math help site would be asking another person for help.**."

In the past there have been many occasions of people cheating on this site, so as always, please keep an eye out for current round problems.

Here is a pdf of the round 1 problems: http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_30_1.pdf

Thanks,

Shrey Joshi

EDIT: Round 2 has been released here: http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_30_2.pdf

EDIT 2: Round 3 has been released here: http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_30_3.pdf

Comment: ... Thanks for the reminder! +1... I'm taking the contest

Comment: This contest is for *middle school* students?! I was just reading through them and thinking they are quite interesting and not so trivial problems...

Comment: @user7530 the competition is open to them, but is generally designed more with high-school students in mind. There's no reason to bar younger students from participating, though.

Comment: Guys, please take a look at the questions.  There was already a successful cheating attempt on my main site, PSE, and we should be expecting cheating attempts here as well.  We need to delete blatant USAMTS questions on MSE as soon as they appear.

Comment: @user7530 This contest is for anyone, including middle school...

Comment: Huh... it spells $30$ in given. I'd like to have puzzle making skills like the creators...

Comment: Why is it our job to police this? "The USAMTS is run on the honor system"

Comment: @jsj Because most of the contributors here empathize with the honest math competitors and despise cheaters to such contests.  This is an ongoing contest, not a past one.

Comment: In [past](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21436/117057) [years](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24989/117057), we have had language in this post to request that users "flag them for moderator attention when you see them so that we can lock them as per our [policy on ongoing contest problems](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774/117057)."

Comment: @jsj Honor systems don't just magically perpetuate themselves. They work because people support them, so that's what we're doing. And you might want to take note of the word that DanielV used, "despise". It's not inaccurate.